# Putting quotation marks in TeX document

Tags: xetex, punctuation

Have to put double quotes mark for a sentence. I am using Xetex.
For the input string ``` ``The work'' ```, the output is also ``` ``The work'' ```  whereas it should be `“The work”`. Below is the list of packages and languages I am using.

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setdefaultlanguage{english} \setotherlanguage{sanskrit}
\usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Mangal.TTF}
\newfontfamily\devtransl[Mapping=DevRom]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
``The work''
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 30):

Add the `Ligatures=TeX` option:

```
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
```

After setting this option, `fontspec` takes care that several characters in the input, which should produce a special ligature glyph in the output, are printed in the correct way. Now ``` `` ``` and `''` will become “ and ”, respectively. A further example, now also `--` and `---` will become the en dash – and the em dash —, respectively.

Comment: @AmitBhatt: Nice to read that it works for you! Perhaps mark the answer as "accepted" then,  by clicking the check mark symbol at the left of the answer.